# Find/Copy All Files in a directory via RAPI on WinCE

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-ce, rapi

I'd like to copy all files in a directory from my windows mobile device to PC.
There's no API for that. Also there is no API to list all files in a directory of embedded device.

I think I can list all files in a directory via (RAPI) `CeFindFirstFile` and `CeFindNextFile` functions.

Could you help me how I can? By the way I should do it in C#

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it's a call to `CeFindFirstFile` followed by `CeFindNextFile` until it returns nothing.  For a working C# example, [this Codeplex project](http://rapi.codeplex.com) wraps those calls in the `RAPI.EnumFiles()` method.

Comment: thanks ;) I've done it. string bookmarks = @"\My Documents";
            string pc = @"C:\winmobforensic";
            fl = myRapi.EnumFiles(bookmarks + @"\\*");
            foreach (FileInformation file in fl)
            {


                        myRapi.CopyFileFromDevice(pc + "\\" + file.FileName, bookmarks + "\\" + file.FileName);


            }